# WCF Domain Service (Silverlight RIA) and SharePoint Foundation 2010 BCS Integration

Tags: silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010, ria, domainservices

Would it be possible to use the Domain Service generated in a Silverlight 4 RIA and connect to it via an External Content Type in SharePoint 2010's BCS?

I know that you do not get a WSDL file from the Service web page, but I am not sure that there isn't something that completely prevents it from working at all even if I were able to generate a WSDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to do something similar - and unfortunately, the closest I could find to the WCF RIA services + silverlight experience, using SP 2010 is this: http://ogarshol.blogspot.com/2010/05/wcf-ria-services-10-for-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: Thank you. That's an interesting blog post.